# Running npm build before/after npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm not familiar with `npm` so I might be holding the wrong end of the shovel here...

There is a package on npm that I would like to modify and use in my own project. The package is `angular-crumbs`. I forked the source repo (https://github.com/emilol/angular-crumbs) into my own account (https://github.com/capesean/angular-crumbs) and then run `npm install capesean/angular-crumbs -force`. However, this produces a `node_modules` folder in my project that hasn't been *built* (and whatever else - as I understand it) with the commands in the source repo's package.json file:

```
"build": "npm run clean && npm run transpile && npm run package && npm run minify && npm run copy"
```

i.e. it doesn't have the types, the correct `package.json` file, etc.

So my question is, how do I get the properly-built files (including type definitions, etc.) from my own repo to install or build-after-installing in my target project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about what you're trying to do, are trying to work on the
angular-crumbs source code, or are you trying to use it in your own project as a dependencuy ?

Anyway, running npm install will install all your dependencies so that you can directly use them in your project, those dependencies don't need to be built after they are installed.

In your case you seem to have an angular application (which is completely different from node.js), usually to start an angular app you can run `ng serve` which will build your source code and run an angular server so you can access it on localhost.

Comment: Hi. Yes I’m trying to use crumbs as a dependency in my angular project. However, the owner of that package is not maintaining it so I would like to make a change in my own forked version and then use that. It seems there are some steps that get run between the original GitHub account and the npm package, ie the build step that I mention. So I need to replicate that in my workflow, albeit without using npm as the package source, ie note installing with npm directly from my GitHub account.

Comment: Alright then what you need to do is to work on your crumbs project as a regular angular project, and when you finish your work you can do `npm package` from the cromb folder inside dist folder. This will produce a tgz package that you will be able to use in your other project. Once in your other project, you can run `npm install path/to/your/package` and it should be good. Here is a useful link if you want : https://jinalshah999.medium.com/how-to-build-and-publish-angular-library-a333d6ff12c0

Comment: Thanks, @liguepk - this has helped. I think it's `npm pack` and it might need a bit of tweaking to get it to build into the dist folder, but it's making more sense now.